# Java speech not working

Tags: java, speech-recognition

I found code to recognize speech on a website: http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/~gwilcock/Tartu-2003/L7-Speech/JSAPI/Recognition.html#11644
In the hello world section.
However when I try to run this here are where the errors lay, and the problem fix gives no detail.
[image]

I really just need this to work. If anyone can help me that would be amazing.

Comment: Your project is probably not setup correctly.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @BethanyLouise I don't have .loadJSGF of .commitchanges where are these builds?!

Comment: They appear to be methods belonging to the `Recognizer` class, which you've presumably imported. Can you post the error trace?